# It is showing an error while giving a http request for my practice bank app project can anyone help me

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

It is showing an error while giving a http request for my practice bank app project can anyone help me[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtqYH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNrLV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASdeJ.jpg)

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1000' in undefined
at Object.register (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\services\dataServices.js:9:14)
at C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\index.js:38:32
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at C:\MEAN SEP22\Angular\BANK\Bankserver\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:137:5

i have no idea what to do next and this is my first project.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the community! Is the attached code snippet copied from a class? If so can you please upload the complete code?

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question, pasted as text and formatted as code.  Code needed to understand the question should never be in images or only in external links.  It should be in the question as plain text.

Comment: Also include in your question what debugging you did to troubleshoot the error.  For example, did you look at the values of `this`, `this.userDetails` and `userDetails` right before the line of code that causes the error?  That would be considered basic debugging and should always be done before posting here.  If you have done basic debugging and are still confused about the problem, then include everything you found in from the basic debugging in your question.  Hint: probably the value of `this` is wrong in that function. If that's the case, there's no reason you shouldn't already know that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.